# How to send email to the user with all data input

Tags: vb.net, email

I have two pages the first one will receive all data that are required from the user such as username e.mail and then the same page will do the calculation but when clicking on result button two things should happen:  1-the result and all user inputs should be sent to the second page  2- the same information should be sent to the user email as the e.mail messege

I wrote the e.mail code but I dont know how do put the results as message

Help please

Comment: Winforms? Webforms? MVC? WPF? Can you post your code and explain exactly what is not working?

Comment: The prblems are: 1- I dont no how to send the all results in second page to the sender I wrote the code but I'm not sure if its correct or not 2- I tried to put my e.mail as a user and check if I would recieve the e.mail but nothing has been sent to me

Comment: Your code looks correct. Are you getting any errors when sending the message? Are you sure there is no authentication required to use smtp.live.com, do you have that configured elsewhere?

Comment: No I'm not sure if I just found it in the internet Do suggest any other SmtpClient??                                                        I did not get any errors but  when  I entred my e.mail I did not recieve the e.mail

Comment: You're going to want to insert some spaces or other delimiters between your values like so to make your message readable: `txtUserName.Text.Trim & " " & txtAirTravel.Text.Trim`

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
Try
        Dim mail As MailMessage
        Dim client As SmtpClient
        Dim fromAddress As String
        Dim toAddress As String
        Dim subject As String
        Dim message As String


        fromAddress = "user@hotmail.com"
        toAddress = "user@hotmail.com"

        subject = "Radiation"
        message = "mail sent"


        mail = New MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, message)
        client = New SmtpClient("Smtp.live.com")

        client.Port = 587
        client.EnableSsl = True
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = False

        Dim SMTPUserInfo As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user@hotmail.com", "password")
        client.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo

        client.Send(mail)
        Label1.Text = "sent"
    Catch ex As Exception
        Label1.Text = ex.Message.ToString()
    End Try
```

Comment: answer updated with a working code.most probably you got an error because of the port

Comment: it gives error that catch doesnot appear outside the Try statement